# Repeated-measures multiple regression that takes care of sphericity in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, repeated-measures, sphericity

I'm looking for a way to run a repeated-measures multiple regression in R, which would take care of sphericity - either by applying some corrections (such as Huynh-Feldt), or by avoiding the problem in some other way.

I have 2 factorial repeated measure variables: 3- and 2-level (`roi_ant`, `roi_lat`), and a quantitative between-subject variable (`pred`), and one dependent quantitative variable (`mv`). I want to test for a full model including all possible interactions between the two within-subject and the between-subject variables (i.e., `mv ~ pred * roi_ant * roi_lat`). I am most interested in the slope of `pred` - whether it is different from 0, and whether it changes depending on `roi_ant` and `roi_lat`.

I have tried to do repeated-measures MANCOVA (that would remove the sphericity assumption) using car::Anova package, but if I got [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/car-Anova-Can-it-be-used-for-ANCOVA-with-repeated-measures-factors-td4637324.html) discussion right, `car::Anova()` is not able to handle such a design.

`ezANOVA()` performs ANCOVA with applying corrections for sphericity, but reports only the repeated-measure variables (after removing the influence of the covariate), and does not report anything on the covariate `pred`.

Mixed linear models (`lme4`) should handle this design well, but since `mcmsamp` is still not implemented, it is difficult to get p-values out of them.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: actually, `mcmcsamp()` was implemented for a while (when `lme4` was still in the 0.9999... series I think), but has since been replaced with `confint()`, that provides confidence intervals for an object of class `Mer`. You can use `method="profile"` for intervals based on the profile likelihood (the default), `method="Wald"` for intervals based on the normal distribution (for fixed effects only), and `method="boot"` for bootstrapped CIs. If you want p-values instead of CIs, run your model in `nlme` instead, or compute z tests by computing estimate/standard error.